# How can I put gVim in my gnome-shell favorites?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gvim

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-shell and I would like to have gVim in the favorites bar.

How can I put it there? I can't find it under applications but it is installed.

Comment: I think this bug is related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/13409

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a file called `~/.local/share/applications/gvim.desktop` and copy the following into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=gvim
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Keywords=Plaintext;Write;
Exec=gvim %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=gvim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
```

It should now be in the applications list and you can add it to the favorites bar like any other application.

Comment: Should I reboot the session to make it work?

Comment: Yes, I had to terminate the session (it works). Take note that the icon image didn't work on my Ubuntu 12.04. After searching a bit I found a solution: `Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/vim.png`. Now I have the icon too :)